# How can I get a non-continuous data in a nan array organized in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I going to describe my problem, then I hope that you can help me.

I have the next numeric array in **MATLAB**:

```
A=[1 , 2 , 7 , NaN , NaN , 5.3 , NaN , 8 , 9 , 6 , 5 , 1 , 0 , NaN , NaN]; % (1x15)
```

Now I want to get someway the next information:

```
[a,b]=somefunction(A)
```

where:

```
a = {[1 2 7]; [5.3] ; [8 9 6 5 1 0]}; 
b = {1 3; 6 6 ; 8 13};
```

As you can see, the cell array "a" has the information of "A" without NaN values, but keeping the sequence and interpreting the NaN like a "cut" in the array.

The variable "b" has the information of the cordinates of the begining and ending of each one of the cells in the variable "a" corresponding to the vector array 
"A".

Comment: So, to shortly recap, you're trying to go from a & b to A in Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, I want to make it all in MATLAB.

Comment: Pardon, the original tags were misleading. In that case you'll probably have better luck on [Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use `isnan()` to filter NaNs out. For example: `A(~isnan(A))`

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the thing here is that I want to "cut" the double array and take the information that I request in the description of the problem, saved in a cell array. Because "isnan" just show me the information where is a NaN value, but I was wondering if maybe exist a way to make it with "cellfun" o something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution: matching cell format

## Code

```ml
function [a,b]=somefunction(A)
endindex=find(diff([isnan(A),1])==1);
startindex=find(diff([1,isnan(A)])==-1);
lengths=endindex-startindex+1;

a=mat2cell(A(~isnan(A)).',lengths,1);

b=[startindex(:),endindex(:)];
b=mat2cell(b,ones(1,size(b,1)),ones(1,size(b,2)));
end
```

### Output

```ml
[a,b]=somefunction(A)
a = 

    [3x1 double]
    [    5.3000]
    [6x1 double]


b = 

    [1]    [ 3]
    [6]    [ 6]
    [8]    [13]
```

Comment: no worries... If your interested in working this sort of thing out for yourself in the future the Mathworks documentation as a good starting point! I recommend taking a look at the documentation for the functions used to get a good idea of what is going on in this code. If your stuck on any of it I can comment the code more to give some more description...

Comment: @lisandrojim I just realised this was your first question here welcome to the community! If this answered your question please consider accepting it:  Here are a couple useful links regarding accepting answers: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
v= isnan(A);
w =[ 1 v 1];    
InvV = ~v;    
w2 = [1 InvV 1];    

runs_zeros = find(diff(w)==1)-find(diff(w)==-1); % lenghts of runs of 0's
runs_zeros = runs_zeros - 1;

p=find(diff(v)==1);
r = p - runs_zeros;

b= [];

for ii = 1:length(r)
b= [b, r(ii):p(ii)];
end

a = A(InvV);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I use that code, this is the information that I got: a=[1 2 7 5.3 8 9 6 5 1 0]; b=[1 2 3 6 8 9 10 11 12 13]; and what I need is: a = {[1 2 7];[5.3];[8 9 6 5 1 0]}; and b = {1 3 ; 6 6; 8 13}